# How do I use StarData with HR number as input?

Tags: entity, astronomy

In Mathematica 13.1, it is simple to look up star data using the star name as input, like this:

```
StarData["Capella","EffectiveTemperature"]
```

Instead, is there a way to use the HR number or Hipparcos catalog number instead of the name?  I've tried to generate an entity like this:

```
StarData[EntityClass["Star",EntityProperty["Star","HRNumber",1708]],"EffectiveTemperature"]
```

That doesn't seem to work, either. I would appreciate any ideas on how to use ID numbers like this, rather than names.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note the properties "HRName" and "HRNumber" of the "Star" entities. Note also the entity class EntityClass["Star", "HRObject"], containing all stars with HR identifier. You can get them all with EntityList[EntityClass["Star", "HRObject"]].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice you can reference the entity using the HR number as a string:

```
StarData["HR1708", "EffectiveTemperature"]
(*Quantity[5.1*10^3, "Kelvins"]*)
```

so if you just have an HR number input, we can convert the number `ToString` and `StringJoin` (`<>`) the `"HR"` to the front:

```
getEffectiveTemperature[hrNum_] :=
 (
  str = ToString@hrNum;
  input = "HR" <> str;
  StarData[input, "EffectiveTemperature"]
  )
getEffectiveTemperature[1708]
(*Quantity[5.1*10^3, "Kelvins"]*)
```

As another example, Antares:

````
StarData["Antares", "EffectiveTemperature"]
StarData["Antares", "HRNumber"]
getEffectiveTemperature[%]

(*"
Quantity[3.6*10^3, "Kelvins"]

6134

Quantity[3.6*10^3, "Kelvins"]
*)
```
````